# generate e-mail messages from MS-Word 2011 using Mail app.

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, email, ms-office

I get down to Step 6 in the MS-Word 2011 mail merge manager, Complete Merge, and the generate e-mail messages option is greyed out.

In MS-Word the File>Share> E-mail attachments is active and will connect to and email using Mail app.

I am using Excel as the data source for the Word template which is a donation tax receipt I need to issue for a charity with 100 donors.

Thanks for any help you can offer and this is urgent.

Erin

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MS Word 2011 requires you to use MS Outlook 2011 as your default mail application for the mail merge *email* feature to work.

You will either have to use Outlook as your default email app (even if it's only temporary) or use another solution.

I have heard good things about [SerialMailer](http://www.falkon-ware.com/SerialMailer) although I haven't used it personally. It's not free but you may be able to download a trial. There are versions that work with Mac OS X Snow Leopard and above.

Otherwise, you could search for *Mail Merge* in the Mac App Store (assuming you have it installed - you didn't specify your OS) for other options.

Comment: Ok so I got the outlook 2011 for mac working and now can't get it to send the doc as a pdf versus .doc. I have a list of email addresses, names, donation amounts in an Excel file. I'm merging that with Mail merge manager in word where the donation receipt text is. I then need it to send 100+ donation receipts as pdf attachments so the $ cannot be edited. Can you help with this last step? OS X is 10.9.5

Comment: Hmm, there's no way to do this directly (at least not in Office 2011 - unsure about Office 2016). You could do this using Apple Script, although that will be a little messy since each PDF needs to be unique to each email. In terms of what you're concerned about though, PDFs can easily be edited (many apps allow this), and in some cases even _secured_ PDFs (e.g. password protected ones) can be compromised. So, in a nutshell, there's no _easy_ way to do this without spending some money. Only you can decide how important it is, since you will certainly have all _your_ records  in safe hands.